# Problem of adding a Data Package to the Windows Clipboard in a UWP

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, clipboard

In my UWP Application, I want to implement COPY/PAST functionality. 
For that, I create `CopiedResourceNodes` which saves my information about copied file

```
public class CopiedResourceNodes
{
    public int Info1{ get; set; }
    public string Info2{ get; set; };
    public double Info3{ get; set; }
    public double Info4{ get; set; }
}
```

After that, I  create `DataPackage` class and Set my `CopiedResourceNodes` via SetData method, and I have another method: SetContent to set new created DataPackage with already set `CopiedResourceNodes` into windows' clipboard

```
    public void CopyNode(CopiedResourceNodes resourceNode)
{
    var dataPackage = new DataPackage();
    dataPackage.SetData(ConvertTypeName, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resourceNode));
    Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);
}
```

When I run App and want to copy I get this Exceptions `
[image]

[image]

I am thankfull in advance for every help and advice.

Comment: I tested with the code snippet you provided and everything works fine, it would be better if you can provide more details about the value of `resourceNode`.

Comment: For more details, I have created a test app  [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WQjFyTuHXn7E9ARtiB2GmIIq4-vdPObb/view?usp=sharing) .  The building configuration is set to **Release x64**. Before building, please ensure that the **Common Language Runtime Exception** option is enabled.

Comment: Have you checked my reply about this exception?

Answer (score 1):

This error is reported because of the parameter `formatId` in [DataPackage.SetData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datapackage.setdata?view=winrt-22621), and it is recommended to use [StandardDataFormats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.standarddataformats.text?view=winrt-22621).

> Parameters formatId String Specifies the format of the data. We
> recommend that you set this value by using the **StandardDataFormats
> class**.

```
 dataPackage.SetData(StandardDataFormats.Text, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resourceNode));
```

Use `StandardDataFormats.Text` or `dataPackage.SetText()`, the error disappears. The following code sample I use `try-catch` to test whether `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` has an exception to judge the data in the Clipboard is outside or inside.

Although your original code throws an exception, it has no bad influence on the data and logical judgment of the program and your App run without crashing. You can also keep using your original code.

```
public void Copy(CopiedResourceNodes resourceNode)
{
    var dataPackage = new DataPackage();
    //dataPackage.SetData(StandardDataFormats.Text, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resourceNode));
    dataPackage.SetText(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resourceNode));
    Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);
}


public async Task<CopiedResourceNodes> Past()
{           
    var data = Clipboard.GetContent();   
            
    try
    {
        var json = await data.GetTextAsync();
        var pasteNode = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CopiedResourceNodes>(json);
        return pasteNode;
    }
    catch (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException)
    {

        return new CopiedResourceNodes() { Adders = "OutsideData", Name = "Bob" };
    }                   
            
}
```

Comment: Your solution solved this problem and the error disappeared, but when I copy the JSON in Clipboard the copied data is available for pasting the data outside of the application. We need that the data in the clipboard will reachable only for our application (for that reason we have used a custom formatId). is there any solution for using copied data only in my application?

Comment: You can continue to use the original code (using a custom formatId), your application will not crash because of that exception.